# Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least on

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

```
Declare @region as nvarchar(30)

Set @region = 'Region'

select SUM([Units_Sold]) 
from Table1 
group by @region, Year
```

`Region` and `Year` are columns and I have to loop through multiple columns and replace the values of `@region`,

but it is showing error as

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Help will be really appreciated

Comment: No, you can't do that, you need `Dynamic SQL` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace identifiers (column names, function names, and so on) with parameters.  So, the value you are inserting is interpreted as a constant, the string `'Region'`, rather than a column reference.  SQL Server detects when any group by key is a constant and it returns an error.

Unfortunately, you need to use dynamic SQL *and* munge the query string:

```
declare @region as nvarchar(30);
set @region = 'Region';

declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'
select SUM([Units_Sold])
from Table1
group by @region, Year
';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@region', @region);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```